# Turning text into icon with content as tooltip with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to turn a hyperlink into an icon while turning the content text into a tooltip. The catch is I'm working in a place where I have only CSS to play with, and I can't modify the HTML or add any Javascript. I'm retrieving data from an external source in a table, and one of the columns is a hyperlink - this I want to transform into an icon with the text-content as a tooltip manner on hover.

Below snipped is how far I've gotten, is there any way of making the `:hover` part look, feel and behave more like a tooltip? Or is there perhaps another way completely to achieve what I'm after?

```css
.external-link {
    font-size: 0;
}

.external-link:after {
    content: ' ';
    background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}

.external-link:hover {
    /* Well it shows the text, but it ain't pretty nor very functional.. */
    font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/" class="external-link">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but it's achievable with modifying `before` and `after` pseudo-elements. You just have to write tooltip content in your `content` property, otherwise, you should modify your HMTL itself.

So your final code should be something like this:

```css
.external-link {
  font-size: 0;
}

.external-link::before {
  content: 'Stack Overflow';
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  /* Position the tooltip text */
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Fade in tooltip */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.external-link::after {
  content: ' ';
  background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

.external-link:hover.external-link::before {
  /* Well it shows the text, but it ain't pretty nor very functional.. */
  font-size: initial;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/" class="external-link">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I see now that I failed to specify I'm looking for a way for it to be dynamic - i.e. the content should always be whatever the content already is... I'll update the question accordingly, and if this isn't possible mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @happytrooper Unfortunately if you have a single element like this, this is not possible to make your tooltip text according to your HTML you should either change your HTML structure or use JS to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit your css like below. Just some idea. Not sure if you can write the tooltip text into css

```css
.external-link {
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.external-link:after {
    content: ' ';
    background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}

.external-link:before {
    content: 'Text';
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
    color: white;
    font-size:initial;
    background: #00000099;
    bottom: -15px;
}

.external-link:hover:before {
    /* Well it shows the text, but it ain't pretty nor very functional.. */
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/" class="external-link">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I see now that I failed to specify I'm looking for a way for it to be dynamic - i.e. the content should always be whatever the content already is... I'll update the question accordingly!